# how to sent mail to "user created" folder instead of "Sent" folder, when the mail was sent using webdav,c# to exchange 2003 server

Tags: c#, webdav, exchange-server-2003

i have created one application which will send and receive mails, so in that application when i send any mail then it should go to "user created" folder instead of "sent" folder of exchange server2003.

I mean it should directly navigate to "user created" folder from the "outbox", it should not go to "sent" folder from "outbox".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the header "Savedestination" to the message.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee178357(v=EXCHG.80).aspx

Comment: HI, i could not understand where to set "savedestination" address as i am using webdav code to send mail. plz specify example

Comment: You are using a PUT command to send the message via the special sendmsg-url, right? Put the "savedestination" as a HTTP header in that request.

Comment: Hi,is it correct? PUTRequest.Headers.Add("Savedestination", "https://" + strServer + "/exchange/" + strAlias + "/Test Sent/"); (Note:- Test Sent is user created folder where i want to store sent mails), but when i use like this...mail send is getting fail

Comment: Do you get any error message? Try to use a relative path like "/exchange/username/test sent" or even only "test sent". You also need to set the "Saveinsent" header to "true".

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reference, i have achieved the required output as per your suggestions.